# problem in Encrypt php code for intellectual property

Tags: php, encryption

I have downloaded phpshadow which is a php encoder
I followed whole of explanation of installing it in the tutorial such as adding php extension which was phpshadow.so
I copied this file in /usr/lib/php5/extensions
and in php.ini 
I wrote this line

extension=phpshadow.so

it is the site:
http://www.phpshadow.com/index.php

I can encrypt my projects successfully

I went to my php pages all of them were encrypted
when I encrypt it it will make a backup from it too

I can't again go to browser and again see my project when I've encrypted it.

How can I encrypt my pages while I can access them too?

I don't know what's wrong with it
I have downloaded a free trial
also I've downloaded phpshadow.licence too

it is the command that I try and then my project will be encrypted:

```
./phpshadow-encoder -l /etc/phpshadow/phpshadow.licence /srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/
```

If you have any other suggestion about encoding files I would be happy to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 45' I made it work!

I tested both standard software version and online version.

**Standard Software Version**

Download the appropriate extension and encoder tool.

Warning! I am working in x64 Linux but I am using a 32bit version of lampp(xampp) and I needed to download the Linux 32bit version to make it work. Otherwise I was getting an "**ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0**" in php error log.

Place the extension in your extension directory and edit your php.ini to include the file like
`extension=phpshadow.so` or `extension="/full/path/phpshadow.so"`

Then download the license and place it in `/etc/phpshadow`.

Use the encoder to encode your php files.

Then test it!

**Problems**

The *free* license has expired since 01/08/2011. You can set your computer clock back to 30/07/2011 and it will work.

Also, let me remind you:

> Note: The free trial licence introduces a 10-second delay on each HTTP request. It is otherwise fully functional

Finally, if you don't place the license file in `/etc/phpshadow` **it won't work**.

**Online Version**

> Encrypt a single .php file under 200 bytes for FREE

Everything except the encryption process works as the Standard Software Version.

*Warning!* You have to download the license for this from [here](http://www.phpshadow.com/onlineversion-download.php).

That license *hasn't expire* yet. Also the online version doesn't introduces the 10-second delay.

Finally, **again** if you don't place the license file in `/etc/phpshadow` **it won't work**.

**TIPS**

- Check your php and webserver error log if something goes wrong
- To change date in linux see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-time-from-linux-command-prompt/)
- You can find your php extension directory in php.ini or use the `phpinfo();` function 
  and look for *extension_dir*
- If your php.ini changes doesn't take place make sure that you are modifying the correct file (in `phpinfo();` look for *Loaded Configuration File*)
- When the **phpshadow.so** is loaded check it with `phpinfo();` or `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());`

Comment: thank you for huge help,I've considered the whole except expiring of license

Comment: I did the whole things that you told me but it is not working are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it in ArchLinux x64, with xampp for linux 1.7.3a. Please check the php and the apache error log for details.

Comment: I found the problem I contacted phpshadow site and finally I found that I had maybe some errors and warnings in my pages that encryption doesn't work but when I encrypted a single page it works then my project had problem not their software thank you master